# What is feathering?

Tags: technology, reentry, terminology

I heard that Virgin Galactic's SpaceShipTwo just tested something called “feathering”.  What is it? How come I didn't hear about the shuttle doing this, it is unique to  Virgin Galactic's ship?

Comment: No, not unique. When I was kid, we had an Estes rocket that used feathering for its descent.

Comment: @DonBranson Haha good one! :) In a sense, all single-stage model rockets use "feathers" to control the damage they do on the neighbors lawn. The good ones even save a bit of the propellant for the final descent explosion to cushion landing by spreading its pieces all over the place. :D

Comment: @TildalWave This one actually ejected the engine and the vanes changed configuration to slow its descent. So, same idea as the SpaceShipTwo. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @DonBranson - Well the difference is that the Estes rocket doesn't carry any passengers or meaningful cargo, so it's not really _"a ship"_. If that wasn't a requirement, then what Richard Branson's analogy of _"smooth and stable descent, just like a shuttlecock"_ is pointing towards the original design predating any Estes rockets, but is itself a copy of nature's own designs, like e.g. the dandelion seeds that predate the humankind. ;)

Comment: Didn't realize you were keying in on the word "ship." Fair enough, an Estes rocket is not a ship, not by anyone's definition. The idea is not unique to rocketry, though it may be unique to "ships."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This latest (second powered) test flight of the [SpaceShipTwo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceShipTwo) was really interesting to watch ([YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=eEmLOU8zTSE#t=134), the "feathering" aerobraking starts at 2:14 into it), but this currently unique to [The Spaceship Company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Spaceship_Company) designs (owned by its sister company [Virgin Galactic](http://www.virgingalactic.com/) that's itself within the [Richard Branson's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Branson) [Virgin Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virgin_Group)) approach to [aerobraking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerobraking) was actually already introduced with the [SpaceShipOne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceShipOne). With the help of a side-by-side image, this is "feathering" of the SpaceShipTwo:

[image]
     <sup>Nominal and "Feathering" wing positions on SpaceShipTwo, side by side comparison (Source: [Space.com](http://www.space.com/13296-photos-virgin-galactic-spaceshiptwo-test-flights.html))</sup>

This is what Wikipedia has to say about [SpaceShipTwo "Feathering"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaceshiptwo#Design_overview):

> SpaceShipTwo uses a feathered reentry system, feasible due to the low
>   speed of reentry – by contrast, the Space Shuttle and other orbital
>   spacecraft re-enter at orbital speeds, closer to 25,000 km/h (16,000
>   mph), using heat shields. SpaceShipTwo is furthermore designed to
>   re-enter the atmosphere at any angle.

And here's another image, showing the movement of the side wings on the SpaceShipTwo (similar approach, source: [The Verge](http://www.theverge.com/2012/7/11/3151861/virgin-galactic-first-space-tourism-flight-next-year)):

[image]

In [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?&v=tqYAQdNWQjQ), Richard Branson explains this feathered reentry system as (starting 55 seconds into the video):

> The wing and tail section would take upwards, into what we call "the
>   feather position", allowing the vehicle to slow its rate of descent
>   smoothly and stably, just like a [shuttlecock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuttlecock).

And here's a technical snapshot of the Virgin Galactic's SpaceShipTwo:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The term "feathering" has different meanings, dependent on context.

In regard to vehicles such as SpaceShip Two, it refers to a high drag aerodynamic configuration which produces a slow, gentle, but steep descent. It only works for vehicles which begin their descent at relatively low airspeed and simply maintains it. Remember that SpaceShip Two ascends more-or-less vertically, and never attains a significant velocity in the horizontal. Use of the term in this context was probably inspired by the notion of a falling feather.

This would not have been practical for the Space Shuttle because the Shuttle re-entered from orbital velocity. It had to manage its drag profile very carefully to avoid excess g-forces and heat build-up. Also, the Shuttle has very high wing loading (mass per unit wing surface); it required high airspeed to maintain lift, practically the opposite of what SpaceShip Two's feathering approach is all about.

Incidentally, "feathering" has another meaning in aviation. It refers to a setting for a variable-pitch propeller. If an engine fails, the propeller can be "feathered" to minimize drag.

Comment: More colorfully: coming in from orbit, the Shuttle's landing approach started at Mach 25.  At that speed any "feathering" rips the feathers off.